# Moment.js set current time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using **moment.js** for timer countdown.
Countdown starts from diff of server side provided time and user side PC time.

**Question is not about simple timezone setting, but incorrect time**

Lets imagine that at user side time is wrong, not only timezone is different but also time is incorrect ( e.g. it should be 15:20 but at user side is 16:25 )

**So i was wondering if it is possible to correct user side time ?**
Setup/initialize moment.js so that it will receive server time 15:20 by some setting and e.g. upon request what is current time will return 15:20 already ?

Or is there such solution in **Javascipt** ?

Comment: You could assume that your server time is correct in UTC. Then make adjustments for everyone else on their actual time zone.

Comment: @GetSet with timezone all is clear but what if at client PC is set wrong time. E.g. at client region current and correct time is 16:20 but his PC clock displays 16:25 cause client setup his time manually

Comment: If the user's timezone is correct, then the UTC could be used to derive the correct time of the user's PC regardless of what "time" is set. Since the UTC doesn't vary. So if they are "-4" on timezone, then subtract 4 from the UTC

Comment: @GetSet aha i see, ok then, if you want you can post it as answer i will accept it

Comment: I did a solution on it in php. But since you are using moment.js, my port to vanilla js wont be elegant. But the basic idea is you would likely want to use your existing api with moment.js to subtract (or add "hours") to the datetime instance, with some care involved for daylight savings time where applicable.